# Xcode autocomplete missing "if" statement

Tags: autocomplete, xcode5.1

As of a couple of days ago, every time I type out `if`, autocomplete no longer writes out:

```
      if (expression){ 
      }
```

but instead autocomplete gives me the macro `ifa_broadaddr`

This has started to drive me crazy, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I followed instructions on this site: http://sealedabstract.com/code/when-xcode-4s-code-completion-autocomplete-breaks/ and it worked again. :)